# Eyebrow- hair removal

Tags: hair

I have some long hairs growing out by my eyebrows, and it bothers my wife, am I able to remove them with my fingers? Same with hairs growing by my ears. or this is Lo Silbash? Appreciate it

Comment: Hi and welcome to MY, we hope you won't mind but we closed your question because of the way it was phrased - seeking a personal ruling. If you wish to make the question more general, edit it and make sure to check the option declaring the edits fix the reasons it was closed and the community can vote to open it again. Looking forward to learning with you in future! We hope you are _here_ to _s(t)ay_, good shabbos

Comment: By that token, please be careful with advice you may see in answers below. We don't know who any of the posters are that we should trust them, and we don't know your specific situation, so it's best to check with a rabbi who knows you to get the right ruling for you.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach, cited in Nishmat  Avraham, Yoreah Deah, page 140 allows fixing a unibrow and the same with long hairs in eyebows.
This would also apply by hair growing by the ears based off the above.

Look at these for more info:

https://www.torahmusings.com/2016/06/the-unibrow-in-halakhah/
https://dinonline.org/2011/09/11/grooming-and-eyebrow-removal/